# No relatório da pesquisa, como faço para alterar o tipo de informação para Criado Por?

Tags: sharepoint

Olá,
Tenho uma pesquisa no Sharepoint 2013 e preciso alterar o campo Criado Por.
Preciso que nele venha o usuário de rede do usuário que criou a resposta.

Hoje por padrão vem o nome Completo.

Se fosse uma lista comum eu poderia alterar facilmente este tipo de representação do nome.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

Consegui acessar a representação deste campo através da url abaixo:

http://site/_layouts/15/FldEditEx.aspx?List=ListID&Field=Author

Não sei se é esta a melhor forma de faze-lo, mas resolveu meu problema.

Abs